# Limit cart quantity of products that contain a specific category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to display a message if the amount of products belonging to a specific category id has a quantity of > 3.

Here is what I have so far, maybe set up and "if" statement if the products contain the category id?

```
    <?php
     $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
     $items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
     $class2 = "hide";
     $count = 0;


   foreach ($items as $item) {

     $categories = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();

     foreach ($categories as $categoryId){

       if($categoryId == 125) $count++;   
     }

     if($count > 3) $class2 = "show";
      }
    ?>

    <div class="<?php echo $class2; ?> warning">
        <p style="margin:0;" class="red">Flash Sale Quantity Is Limited To 3</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this would do the trick... First step is find the category id, then start counting within the if statement and if `$count` is `>3`, then `$class2` will be `"show"`;

```
<?php
 $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
 $items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
 $class2 = "hide";
 $count = 0;

 foreach ($items as $item) {

    $categories = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();

    foreach ($categories as $categoryId){

        if($categoryId == 125) { 

            if($count > 3) { $class2 = "show" }

            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }   
 }

?>

<div class="<?php echo $class2; ?> warning">
    <p style="margin:0;" class="red">Flash Sale Quantity Is Limited To 3</p>
</div>
```